# Getting JSON data From a URL Which contains .SVC?wsdl file in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, json, post, xcode4.2

Someone please help me in this query.

How to Get JSON data From a URL Which contains .SVC file in iphone (ios5)?

The link is like : http://156.160.45.118/api/Login.svc?wsdl (not original)

and parameters are: email and password.

So how can I verify the login credentials?

My code :

```
NSString *username = emailField.text;
 NSString *password = passwordField.text;
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [dictionnary setObject:username forKey:@"user_email"];
 [dictionnary setObject:password forKey:@"user_password"];

 NSError *error = nil;
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
 options:kNilOptions
 error:&error];   

 NSString *urlString = @"http://156.160.45.118/api/Login.svc?wsdl";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

 // Prepare the request
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
 [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
 [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];    

 NSError *errorReturned = nil;
 NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
 NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
 returningResponse:&theResponse
 error:&errorReturned];
 if (errorReturned) 
 {
 //...handle the error
 }
 else 
 {
 NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"%@", retVal);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks Graham . Please check the question again i edited.

Comment: I downvoted because your question was initially "Please give me some code" and you hadn't shown what you'd already tried, or shown any effort of your own. I see you have now edited your question, but it won't let me remove my downvote.

Comment: @ok Graham No Problem .But If you have any solution then Pls Post here

Comment: Just search for JSON iPhone. I'm sure you'll find lots of sample code

Comment: @Nick Actually i tried with above code and not Finding the result.So i don't know where i m going wrong.Someone please findout this.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota Your code above doesn't show any attempt at accessing JSON data. If you do some searching you'll find lots of examples which you can then apply. We are here to help, not to do your work for you.

Comment: @Nick I,m Searching for this since Two Days and Not getting any Working Solution.i have idea how to parse JSON webservice using JSON Framework.But its kind a WSDL type of  webservice which is totally new concept for me.Ex :link :http://156.160.45.118/api/Login.svc?wsdl i need only some idea or any Example or any link which contains solution for this question.i can't understand how to post the parameters like "username" and "Password" and get the response Like "Success" or "failure" .finally i don't want anyone to be work for me i just need some help or some links.

Comment: Edit your question with JSON response...anyone definitely not helping you without seen your response code.

Comment: You say you don't want anyone to do your work for you - first step would have been for you to read up what JSON is. Then you would've realised that the response isn't JSON. You've got an error message being returned by the service "Endpoint not found". Google this message and you'll see the reason.

Comment: @Nick I know the Responce is not JSON Thats why i m Asking Where i m doing Wrong ?is there any fault in my code or the issue from server side ?I Should get the JSON responce Like "Success" or "Failed".I m new for this type of webservice thats why i can't find the fault.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota And what did you discover when you searched the internet for "Endpoint not found" ?

Comment: @Nick I got Something like :"I would think WCF is giving the error because it really can't find the endpoint You need to have at lest one endpoint for the service host to start. You can either do this in code, or in the app.config file."

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota Does that not give you an idea? Seriously? I'm not wanting to sound harsh, but it seems to me that you're not taking the time to look at the information in front of you. Have you checked your service is actually working properly and that it HAS AN ENDPOINT? Have you tried connecting to your service outside of your code in case it is your SERVER, not your client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got my answer By researching lot of things.

```
NSString *username = emailField.text;
        NSString *password = passwordField.text;
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dictionnary setObject:username forKey:@"user_email"];
        [dictionnary setObject:password forKey:@"user_password"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                           options:kNilOptions
                                                             error:&error];   

        NSString *urlString = http://156.160.45.118/api/Login.svc/login;

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
        NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
        NSError *requestError = NULL;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
         NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

Comment: i'm getting problem in this svc concept. can you explan?

Comment: Can you Submit your Code ? And explain what is the problem , i will try to help you out.